# Insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, web3js, ether

Sending Address has over 1 Eth in current Balance.

Using the `Geth` console, I can send many transactions of any amount less than .033

```
eth.sendTransaction({to:'0x8B9da75fda99bAd680154050Ba386523CA3AD112', 
from:'0x62396567241bC92Ee3D082AC3C4144511Ec6c773',
value:web3.toWei(.033,'ether'),gas:30000})

"0x113dd5b9c8bb6d48fe2b3ef16576905f6e46aa4ed6cd080120a2aaf54113e7b4"
```

If I try to send .034 ETH or greater, then I always get this error.

> eth.sendTransaction({to:'0x8B9da75fda99bAd680154050Ba386523CA3AD112', 
> from:'0x62396567241bC92Ee3D082AC3C4144511Ec6c773',value:web3.toWei(.034
> ,'ether'),gas:30000}) Insufficient funds for gas * price + value 
>   
> at web3.js:3119:20 
>   
> at web3.js:6023:15 
>   
> at web3.js:4995:36 
>   
> at :1:1

Comment: are you using that in a private chain or in the public one?

Comment: default geth setup on public chain. Here is .sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Starting geth"
screen -dmS geth /usr/bin/geth --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3"  --verbosity 3

Comment: what is the balance of 0x62396567241bC92Ee3D082AC3C4144511Ec6c773

Comment: 0.7 ETH and I had 1.5 ETH in the account with the same problem. I can send many small transactions, but nothing larger than .33

Comment: yeah me too ,
private chain ;networkId 1108; seems all right, when i invoke a contract ,then error

Answer (score 19):

It seems to be a bug in geth, try the solution presented here : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2173

they assume that the solution is :

> Convert all values to hex (with bc if you use bash)
>
> Make sure to specify both gas and gasPrice! Enclose all values in single quotes
> eth.sendTransaction({from:'0x123456', to:'0x123456',
> value: '0x8AC4270ACC4B7FF7', gas: '0x5208', gasPrice:
> '0x4A817C800'});"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to solve my issue by upgrading geth to: Geth/v1.4.16-stable/linux/go1.6.2

Comment: hex value fixed my issue

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to add an important information:

gas * price + value really means **MAXGas** * price.

In my case transactions failed from time to time when gas price increased because gas limit was set too high! Even if you know that it won't be that expensive you should use a reasonable amount.

Comment: Mind blown!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve my issue by upgrading geth to: Geth/v1.4.16-stable/linux/go1.6.2

Comment: This error is common if you don't have enough eth in your account, if your node isn't in sync with the network, or if you don't specify a gas price or something else is slightly wrong with the command. In this case, I'm guessing it was the attacks on the network causing your node not to be 100% in line with reality or timing out or something similar, which is why upgrading fixed it.

Comment: After upgrading I was able to send 40 valid transactions. But after I sent the transactions I found that my node was stuck on one block for 30 minutes. I then stopped Geth and ran the geth upgradedb command. Waiting for this command to finish. Hopefully everything will be resolved now.

Comment: I should manually specify gas price?

Comment: I would recommend it. Usually I do 21000000000 but I've been using 25000000000 lately. Not sure if it actually makes a difference.

Comment: Also had this issue when accidentally upgraded t0 Geth/v1.5 beta

Answer (score 5):

i solved this by reducing my gas

Comment: Where did you reduce the gas?

Comment: The example of @manas-agrawal show how to set a reasonalbe gas value for a private chain.

Answer (score 3):

```
gas:4.7M, gasPrice:101 GWei => error: insufficient funds.
gas:3.7M, gasPrice:101 GWei => it works ok.
gas:4.7M, gasPrice:100 GWei => error: insufficient funds.
gas:4.7M, gasPrice:90 GWei  => error: insufficient funds.
gas:4.7M, gasPrice:70 GWei  => it works ok.
gas:4.7M, gasPrice:80 GWei  => it works ok.
gas:4.7M, gasPrice:85 GWei  => error: insufficient funds.
gas:4.7M, gasPrice:82 GWei  => it works ok.
...
gas:1.0M, gasPrice:10 GWei  => it works ok.
```

So, there is a (variable?) **limit** for **gas*gasPrice** that throws the error. Using gas and prices lower and far from this limit is probably the safer approach.

Answer (score 2):

In my private Ethereum Blockchain network, I resolved the issue by changing the `chainId` variable in my genesis block code to any random number except 0.

Please find the code for my genesis block below:

```
{
"config":{
        "chainId": 45,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 12
    },
  "alloc"      : {},
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x20000",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

I hope it might be helpful for you.

Comment: Does not work. It is already 2019 in my case. Still facing this issue.

Comment: (I'd write a full answer, but haven't the reputation). The reason for this answer is that if the tx signer is misconfigured, the error cited will awkwardly and unhelpfully be thrown. Check if the chain you're using has Homestead (**EIP2**) _and/or_ **EIP155** configured for its current block number. Transaction configuration (what fields need to be filled or omitted) will depend on the interface you're using and your chain's protocol current upgrades. See https://github.com/etclabscore/core-geth/blob/master/core/types/transaction_signing.go#L42 for code reference.

Comment: Chain id is just a number to recognize your network among others. It should not cause such issue, the real cause somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue using Sepolia Test Network. In the **truffle-config.js** file I copied and pasted another network setting to create one for Sepolia. This configuration came with default **gas** and **gasPrice** parameter values. I removed them and let Sepolia dictate the default values for those parameters.

At the end my Sepolia config section was:

```
sepolia: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic,url_to_infuria_service),
  network_id: 11155111,
}
```

}

Error was gone, and truffle log showed the the total cost for the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

This error message `Get an error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value` might be caused by chain misconfiguration. I faced it with my own private chain.

In my case I had a working private chain and have to deploy a new one which should act as testnet. This new requirements lead to some refactoring on the client side and after this I start getting `Get an error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value` error one both new testnet and previously working private chain. The root cause was I passed an account address instead of its private key when execute operation from the mobile client.