# Geth SendTransaction: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, geth-debugging, cli

I have looked at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/insufficient-funds-for-gas-price-value) similar question but I think my problem is a little different.

I am using Geth to try and send 0.9 eth from one cli wallet to another, using this command in my bash shell terminal:

`sudo geth --exec "eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:'9866c73a755da3d434cfdc8bca8fed02eebad469', value: web3.toWei(0.9, 'ether')})" attach`

I currently have 0.99 Ethereum in my wallet, so I should have enough to do the transfer. I am using the mainnet. I left the gas amount blank so that geth works out how much I need to spend.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure your geth is synchronized with the blockchain?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen yes I am synced

Comment: Gas estimation can err. This might be such a cash. I would lower the amount and add gas higher that you estimate `{from: eth.coinbase, value: amount gas: amount ...`. A lot depends on the receiver, so this experiment will help rule out incorrect gas estimation.

Comment: Ok thanks @Rob. Seems that Geth is a pretty scuffed program when it can't even do simple transaction commands in an easy way